# Only keep laptop power on when second screen is plugged in

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, power-management, lid

My current home setup consists of my laptop plugged into my monitor. I have changed my power settings to keep my computer turned on when I'm plugged into an outlet and close my lid.
But when I'm away from my monitor and close the lid while my laptop is plugged into an outlet, it also keeps running.
*I would like to know if there is a way how I can program my laptop in such a way that it only stays on when its plugged into an outlet **and** into my monitor?*
I know its not the end of the world if its not possible but I'm just interested.
I've already looked into using Regedit but couldn't find anything...
Thank you for reading this

Comment: Is this the only monitor on the computer? Does the laptop have in addition an integrated display adapter?

Comment: There is only one HDMI port, which is used for my only external monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Some information on doing these checks in PowerShell is described below.

**Checking for AC power**

```
if((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Battery -Property BatteryStatus).BatteryStatus -eq 2)
```

**Checking for monitor active**

To see the status of all your monitors, enter this command:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams
```

Identify the `InstanceName` of the external monitor (normally listed second),
and let's assume its name is `DISPLAY\ACR049D\5&2f01ee6d&0&UID4358_0`.
You can query its `Active` status as:

```
if((Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams -Filter "InstanceName = 'DISPLAY\\ACR049D\\5&2f01ee6d&0&UID4358_0'").Active -eq 'True')
```

Note the doubling of the backslashes in the string.